# Security issue with hyperledger fabric's chain code (smart contract)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, smartcontracts

I was reading through the documentation of Hyperledger Fabric and found a very confusing aspect. I do not know if it really is a security issue or if I have misunderstood something.

From [this section](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/network/network.html#applications-and-smart-contract-chaincode) of the documentation, what I understood is the `interface` of the smart contract needs to be the same when it is instantiated on different peers. Does that mean that I can have different business logic within the smart contract functions while having same interface when deploying it to different peers?

If I am correct, doesn't this mean a BIG security issue in the design? Any help in understanding the concept better would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chaincode interface is strictly defined and cannot be changed, the interface is:

```
// Chaincode interface must be implemented by all chaincodes. The fabric runs
// the transactions by calling these functions as specified.
type Chaincode interface {
    // Init is called during Instantiate transaction after the chaincode container
    // has been established for the first time, allowing the chaincode to
    // initialize its internal data
    Init(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response

    // Invoke is called to update or query the ledger in a proposal transaction.
    // Updated state variables are not committed to the ledger until the
    // transaction is committed.
    Invoke(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response
}
```

You have one method to handle initialization aspect of you logic while rest would be executed via `Invoke` method. Now, during chaincode install/instantiation computed hash of the chaincode and persisted within lifecycle namespace bound to chaincode. Therefore if another peer will have different binary code and will try to use it, peer will fail to execute it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But how would it decide which peer's binary code is the valid one?

Comment: The one you have used to instantiate chaincode on channel